# Gitlab CI/CD: deploy docker image to existing kubernetes cluster

Tags: docker, kubernetes, gitlab, gitlab-ci, kops

I have node.js application that I need to deploy to exising kubernetes cluster.

The cluster is setup using `kops` on AWS.

I have created `.gitlab-ci.yml` file for building docker images.

So, whenever a change is pushed to either `master` or `develop` branch. It will build the docker image.

I have already followed steps defined [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/clusters/add_remove_clusters.html#existing-kubernetes-cluster) to add an existing cluster.

Now, I have to roll update to exisitng kubernetes cluster..

```
# This file is a template, and might need editing before it works on your project.
docker-build-master:
  # Official docker image.
  image: docker:latest
  stage: build
  services:
    - docker:dind
  before_script:
    - docker login -u "$CI_REGISTRY_USER" -p "$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD" $CI_REGISTRY
  script:
    - docker build --pull -t "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:prod" .
    - docker push "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:prod"
  only:
    - master

docker-build-dev:
  # Official docker image.
  image: docker:latest
  stage: build
  services:
    - docker:dind
  before_script:
    - docker login -u "$CI_REGISTRY_USER" -p "$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD" $CI_REGISTRY
  script:
    - docker build --pull -t "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:dev" .
    - docker push "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:dev"
  only:
    - develop
```

For now, I am using shared runner.

*How can I integrate kubernetes deployment after image is built with gitlab ci/cd to deploy on aws (cluster is created with kops)?*

*For registry I am using gitlab's container registry not docker hub.*

**Update**

I changed configuration and doing  below,

```
stages:
  - docker-build
  - deploy

docker-build-master:
  image: docker:latest
  stage: docker-build
  services:
    - docker:dind
  before_script:
    - docker login -u "$CI_REGISTRY_USER" -p "$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD" $CI_REGISTRY
  script:
    - docker build --pull -t "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:prod" .
    - docker push "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:prod"
  only:
    - master

deploy-prod:
  stage: deploy
  image: roffe/kubectl
  script:
    - kubectl apply -f scheduler-deployment.yaml
  only:
    - master


docker-build-dev:
  image: docker:latest
  stage: docker-build
  services:
    - docker:dind
  before_script:
    - docker login -u "$CI_REGISTRY_USER" -p "$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD" $CI_REGISTRY
  script:
    - docker build --pull -t "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:dev" .
    - docker push "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:dev"
  only:
    - develop
```

But now I am getting below error.

```
roffe/kubectl with digest roffe/kubectl@sha256:ba13f8ffc55c83a7ca98a6e1337689fad8a5df418cb160fa1a741c80f42979bf ...
$ kubectl apply -f scheduler-deployment.yaml
error: the path "scheduler-deployment.yaml" does not exist
Cleaning up file based variables
00:01
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

File `scheduler-deployment.yaml` does exist in the root directory.

Comment: Well, you're already deploying to digitalocean, so what issues are you running into changing that to use AWS?

Comment: @OneCricketeer That's another cluster and another service, which is setup with github workflow. This cluster is different, and it is using Gitlab CI/CD not github actions, and also this cluster is also hosted on aws ec2. Now I have removed that reference from the question to avoid the consufions. I listed that only as an example.

Comment: Regardless of where/how things are running, do you not understand how to config the kubeconfig to point at the AWS cluster as part of the pipeline?

Comment: I suggest using Flux for deploying rather than invoking kubectl as part of the pipeline, though https://toolkit.fluxcd.io/guides/installation/#gitlab-and-gitlab-enterprise

Comment: @OneCricketeer Yes, I don't understand the flow of deployment to k8s cluster using gitlab CI/CD. Thanks for the link, I will study flux. I haven't used it before.

Comment: @OneCricketeer Will flux also create  docker images to deploy? How would I configure to trigger build, also for which branch?

Comment: This looks more appropriate for DevOps.SE

Comment: I have a very similar setup to yours @confusedWarrior, this is how I added my GKE cluster - [https://docs.gitlab.com/...](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/clusters/add_remove_clusters.html#existing-kubernetes-cluster) - I connected it as a self-managed cluster to avoid Gitlab managing the cluster for me. I add the cluster on a group level, and I have been using `lachlanevenson/k8s-kubectl:latest` image for years now without any issues.

Comment: @Barend I have done the same, but I am not able to access `kubectl` inside `gitlab-ci.yml`. I tried above method using an image for `kubectl` but getting `can't find the file error`

Comment: 1) regarding the error, your files are not mounted in the container working directory 2) You still need to config kubectl to the AWS cluster 3) You can use projects like kaniko to build images within your cluster, otherwise build and push the images yourself from gitlab https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/kaniko

Comment: Why I can't just pass the cluster configuration to kubectl and use the command to deploy? Gitlab exposes environment variable for configuration `$KUBECONFIG`? I ma not using AWs managed cluster. I have setup the cluster using `kops` . I have already added existing cluster to gitlab.

Comment: @OneCricketeer Please see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66648803/bin-bash-line-117-kubectl-command-not-found-gitlab-ci

Answer (score 1):

> I suggest using Flux for deploying rather than invoking kubectl as part of the pipeline,

That would be true because:

- the traditional [GitOps with the agent for Kubernetes](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/clusters/agent/gitops/agent.html) has been deprecated with GitLab 16.2 (July 2023), and [replaced with Flux](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/clusters/agent/gitops.html), as shown [in this tutorial](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/clusters/agent/gitops/flux_tutorial.html).
- [GitLab 16.3](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2023/08/22/gitlab-16-3-released/#flux-sync-status-visualization) (August 2023) adds:

  > ### Flux sync status visualization
  >
  > In previous releases, you probably used `kubectl` or another third-party tool to check the status of your Flux deployments. From GitLab 16.3, you can check your deployments with the environments UI.
  >
  > Deployments rely on Flux `Kustomization` and `HelmRelease` resources to gather the status of a given environment, which requires a namespace to be configured for the environment. By default, GitLab searches the `Kustomization` and `HelmRelease` resources for the name of the project slug. You can customize the name GitLab looks for in the environment settings.
  >
  > [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/16_3/flux-badges.png -- Flux sync status visualization]
  >
  > See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/environments/kubernetes_dashboard.html#flux-sync-status) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/391581).