# /bin/bash: line 117: kubectl: command not found gitlab-ci

Tags: docker, kubernetes, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am not able to use `kubectl` command inside `gitlab-ci.yml` file.

I have already gone through the steps mentioned in the doc to add an existing cluster in the [doc](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/clusters/add_remove_clusters.html#existing-kubernetes-cluster).

Nowhere they have mentioned, How can I use `kubectl`.

I tried the below configuration.

```
stages:
  - docker-build
  - deploy

docker-build-master:
  image: docker:latest
  stage: docker-build
  services:
    - docker:dind
  before_script:
    - docker login -u "$CI_REGISTRY_USER" -p "$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD" $CI_REGISTRY
  script:
    - docker build --pull -t "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:prod" .
    - docker push "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:prod"
  only:
    - master

deploy-prod:
  stage: deploy
  image: roffe/kubectl
  script:
    - kubectl apply -f scheduler-deployment.yaml
  only:
    - master
```

But I am getting below error,

```
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
00:01
Using docker image sha256:c8d24d490701efec4c8d544978b3e4ecc4855475a221b002a8f9e5e473398805 for roffe/kubectl with digest roffe/kubectl@sha256:ba13f8ffc55c83a7ca98a6e1337689fad8a5df418cb160fa1a741c80f42979bf ...
$ kubectl apply -f scheduler-deployment.yaml
error: unable to recognize "scheduler-deployment.yaml": Get http://localhost:8080/api?timeout=32s: dial tcp [::1]:8080: connect: connection refused
Cleaning up file based variables
00:00
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Clearly, it is not able to connect to the cluster, or maybe trying to connect to the cluster inside this `roffe/kubectl` image container.

When I remove the image, I get this error.

```
/bin/bash: line 117: kubectl: command not found
```

I have gone through the whole doc I couldn't find a single example or reference that explains this part.

Please suggest how I can deploy to the existing k8s cluster.

*Update*

I went through this [doc](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/clusters/index.html#deployment-variables) and I am using defined variables in my gitlab-ci.yml to update the context of the kubectl.

But still it doesn't work.

```
deploy-prod:
  stage: deploy
  image: roffe/kubectl
  script:
    - echo $HOME
    - echo $KUBECONFIG
    - echo $KUBE_URL
    - mkdir -p $HOME/.kube
    - echo -n $KUBECONFIG | base64 -d > $HOME/.kube/config
    - kubectl get pods
  only:
    - master
```

Error that I get,

```
$ echo $HOME
/root
$ echo $KUBECONFIG
$ echo $KUBE_URL
$ mkdir -p $HOME/.kube
$ echo -n $KUBECONFIG | base64 -d > $HOME/.kube/config
$ kubectl get pods
The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
Cleaning up file based variables
00:01
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Comment: `roffe/kubectl` image is just having `bash`, `kubectl`, `gettext`. It does not have a local kubernetes cluster. `kubectl` is your client-side application, you have to configure `kubectl` to connect to a cluster

Comment: @JeffyMathew Please suggest or share any reference I could that.

Comment: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/overview/ please refer this. You've to create a cluster somewhere and provide it's credentials to `kubectl` so that it can connect

Comment: I have already setup an existing cluster in gitlab. How can I reference that in gitlab-ci.yml file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To automate deployment with an existing cluster, You need to follow below steps:

*1. Add you cluster to gitlab project.*

Follow [this doc](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/clusters/add_remove_clusters.html#existing-kubernetes-cluster), and add your existing cluster

*2. Build your project and push to docker or any registry*

```
stages:
  - docker-build
  - deploy

docker-build-master:
  image: docker:latest
  stage: docker-build
  services:
    - docker:dind
  before_script:
    - docker login -u "$CI_REGISTRY_USER" -p "$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD" $CI_REGISTRY
  script:
    - docker build --pull -t "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:prod" .
    - docker push "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:prod"
  only:
    - master
```

*3. Apply your deployment.yml to cluster*

To use `kubectl` inside `gitlab-ci.yml`, you need an image that has `kubectl`. The one that you have used will work.

But the `kubectl` inside the container has no idea about the context of cluster that you added earlier.

Now this is where gitlab's envrionment variable play their role.

> The default environment scope is *, which means all jobs, regardless of their environment, use that cluster. Each scope can be used only by a single cluster in a project, and a validation error occurs if otherwise. Also, jobs that don’t have an environment keyword set can’t access any cluster. [see here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/clusters/index.html#multiple-kubernetes-clusters)

So, when you added your cluster, it goes by default in scope `*` and will be passed to every job provided it uses some environment.

Also, When you create a cluster, gitlab create environment variables for that cluster by default, [see here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/clusters/index.html#deployment-variables).

Important thing to notice is that it also adds an environment variable `KUBECONFIG`.

---

In order to access your Kubernetes cluster, `kubectl` uses a configuration file. The default `kubectl` configuration file is located at  `~/.kube/config` and is referred to as the `kubeconfig` file.

`kubeconfig` files organize information about clusters, users, namespaces, and authentication mechanisms. The `kubectl` command uses these files to find the information it needs to choose a cluster and communicate with it.

The loading order follows these rules:

- If the `--kubeconfig` flag is set, then only the given file is loaded. The flag may only be set once and no merging takes place.
- If the `$KUBECONFIG` environment variable is set, then it is parsed as a list of filesystem paths according to the normal path delimiting rules for your system.
- Otherwise, the `${HOME}/.kube/config` file is used and no merging takes place.

So, `kubectl` command can use the variable `KUBECONFIG` to set the context [see here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/organize-cluster-access-kubeconfig/#merging-kubeconfig-files).

So, your deployment job will be like below,

```
deploy-prod:
  stage: deploy
  image: roffe/kubectl
  script:
    - kubectl get pods
    - kubectl get all
    - kubectl get namespaces
    - kubectl apply -f scheduler-deployment.yaml
  environment:
    name: production
    kubernetes:
      namespace: default
  only:
    - master
```

*You can also set a  namespace  for the job with `environment.kubernetes.namespace`*

Answer (score 0):

this image ***(roffe/kubectl)*** doesn't have kubectl package so you can add some package kubectl and configuration to connect your kubernetes cluster.

Comment: Thanks, but how can I achieve that?

Comment: @ljosalfar `roffe/kubectl` has `kubectl` installed, `/bin/bash: line 117: kubectl: command not found` error is shown when the image in the runner is changed from `roffe/kubectl`

Comment: @JeffyMathew Where it is being changed? Can you please answer it with details.